# Are addons generally considered safe to download and install?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, installation, encoding

Are addons considered safe to download? I mean, it seems that anyone can make their own addon. Who's to say if they're safe or not?

Comment: nobody. But if someone makes an unsafe (virus) add-on he won't earn much in future ...wouldn't he? it's like every software - it can always be a virus.

Comment: And like any software, common sense would require everyone to research out about what they want to download beforehand, or at least avoid products or authors unknown from everyone, and only download from the author's official channels.